# TextRazor with XML file

Tags: python, xml, file

I will extract data from an XML file and applied TextRazor.
Here my code:

```
from lxml import etree
import textrazor
tree = etree.parse("wordlist.xml")
c=' '
for user in tree.xpath("/item/str",encoding="utf-8"):
   c += user.text
textrazor.api_key = "5522666"
client = textrazor.TextRazor(extractors=["word","entities", "topics","sentence","words"])
response = client.analyze(c)
def calcul(response):
   cmd = ''
   for entity in response.entities():
        print(entity.id, entity.relevance_score, entity.confidence_score,
        entity.freebase_types) 
        cmd += str(entity.id) + str(entity.relevance_score) + str(entity.confidence_score) + 
        str(entity.freebase_types) + '\n'
   return str(cmd)
print(calcul(response))
```

But i have an error:

TextRazorAnalysisException: TextRazor returned HTTP Code 400: b'{"time":0,"error":"TextRazor cannot analyze documents of language: ind . If you know the language of your documents beforehand, consider setting the 'languageOverride' paramater. ","ok":false}'

Someone can help me please.

Comment: Do not share API key.

Comment: @balderman it's not my API Key

Comment: the error message is giving a hint: have you tried setting that "paramater" (in a paying text-analysis software lol)? i don't think that `encoding` is a valid parameter for your xpath function.